# How To enable KeepAlived

Tags: keepalived

I have compiled and configured `keepalived` on my `raspberry` but it won't start.

When I try `systemctl` enable `keepalived` I got error

```
-------------------------------------------------------
root@haproxy:/etc/systemd/system# /etc/init.d/keepalived status
● keepalived.service - Keepalive Daemon (LVS and VRRP)
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/keepalived.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
Condition: start condition failed at Sun 2018-07-08 10:28:01 UTC; 28s ago
           └─ ConditionFileNotEmpty=/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf was not met

-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image: p]

How to fix this error?
Thx before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mismatch between title and problem as keepalived is already enabled but fails to start.

```
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/keepalived.service; **enabled**; vendor preset: enabled)
```

According to attached message, configuration file (/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf) is empty and preventing keepalived to start due to specified condition (CondtionFileNotEmpty). Add configuration to the file and start keepalived then.

Comment: thanks sir .. sorry for mismatch on question title ..